# NodeJs using Request Promise to call external API, Saving data from the response body

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using a request promise in order to make an API call to the smarty streets API to do address validation. The issue I'm currently stuck on is simply saving the return body of data in order to use it outside the request. What would be the simplest way to save the `body` in the request to my variable `reBody`?

Im sure its a simple issue that I'm overthinking so any help would be much appreciated! Attached is the code below as well as the response body itself.

code:

```
var resBody = null;

request({
    method: 'get',
    uri: url,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true 
})
.then(function (body) {
    console.log(body);
    return body
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});

for (i in resBody){
    console.log(resBody[i].components);
}
```

response:

```
[
  {
    input_index: 0,
    candidate_index: 0,
    delivery_line_1: '1 Campus Dr',
    last_line: 'Allendale MI 49401-9401',
    delivery_point_barcode: '494019401017',
    components: {
      primary_number: '1',
      street_name: 'Campus',
      street_suffix: 'Dr',
      city_name: 'Allendale',
      default_city_name: 'Allendale',
      state_abbreviation: 'MI',
      zipcode: '49401',
      plus4_code: '9401',
      delivery_point: '01',
      delivery_point_check_digit: '7'
    },
    metadata: {
      record_type: 'S',
      zip_type: 'Standard',
      county_fips: '26139',
      county_name: 'Ottawa',
      carrier_route: 'R099',
      congressional_district: '02',
      rdi: 'Commercial',
      elot_sequence: '0002',
      elot_sort: 'A',
      latitude: 42.97192,
      longitude: -85.89169,
      precision: 'Zip9',
      time_zone: 'Eastern',
      utc_offset: -5,
      dst: true
    },
    analysis: {
      dpv_match_code: 'Y',
      dpv_footnotes: 'AABB',
      dpv_cmra: 'N',
      dpv_vacant: 'N',
      active: 'Y',
      footnotes: 'N#'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Put your loop into `.then` block.

Comment: Read up on the Promise API. There's not a lot to it, but it's arguably the single most important thing you need to understand properly in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your for loop inside of the `then` block. Else you can simplify it like this:

```
let resBody = await request({
  method: 'get',
  uri: url,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
  },
  json: true 
});
```

Since it is a promise you can await it. To catch error you can use try..catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Put the for loop inside `.then` block.
2. Use `async/await` to avoid the so-called "callback hell"

I prefer the second option:

```
(async () => {
    try{
        const resBody = await request({
            method: 'get',
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
            },
            json: true
        });
        for (i in resBody) {
            console.log(resBody[i].components);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})();
```

It's clean and allows you to make many requests in a synchronous manner.